# Enable completion for CSS using ctags

Tags: autocompletion, ctags

I have added CSS tags to my project `tags` file by adding this to `~/.ctags`

```
--langdef=css
--langmap=css:.css
--langmap=css:+.scss
--langmap=css:+.sass
--langmap=css:+.styl
--langmap=css:+.less
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ \t\n,]+)+)\{/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/#\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/.\1/c,class,classes/
```

then, after project tags file is updated, it now has entries like this:

```
.bg-danger  public/CSS/framework/components/utilities.css   /^.bg-danger {$/;"  c
.bg-faded   public/CSS/framework/components/utilities.css   /^.bg-faded {$/;"   c
.bg-info    public/CSS/framework/components/utilities.css   /^.bg-info {$/;"    c
```

I would like completion to work when writing html in html or PHP files, e.g. if I am in `-- INSERT --` mode and have a partial like

```
    <div class="bg-d
```

Im trying to get completion assistance with <kbd>Ctrl - x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl - ]</kbd> but vim simply returns

> -- Tag completion (^]^N^P) Pattern not found

Im not fussed whether completion is invoked via the <kbd>Ctrl - ]</kbd> command specifically (but I dont really want to install a plugin for this), I just want completion assistance for CSS classes (and ids) as I type.

Relevant info

- terminal vim - version 7.4.52
- Plugins - ctrlp

Comment: "Completion", not "autocompletion".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the leading dot before class names.

Your search pattern leaves it out but you add it afterwards and, because tag search honors your `iskeyword` setting which doesn't contain `.`, Vim looks for `^foo` instead of `^.foo` in your tag files and, logically, doesn't find it.

You basically have two ways to fix that issue…

**In ctags**

Remove `.` from the second part of your pattern. This will index `.foo` as `foo` and allow Vim to find it when doing tag-based completion.

```
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/.\1/c,class,classes/
```

becomes:

```
--regex-css=/^[ \t]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/c,class,classes/
```

**In Vim**

Add `.` to the `iskeyword` option to allow Vim to search for `^.foo` instead of `^foo`:

```
set iskeyword+=.
```

---

Note that both methods probably have shortcomings so it may be a good idea to do some real world testing.

You might find my [`.ctags`](https://gist.github.com/romainl/085b4db4a26a06ec7e16) interesting.

Comment: aha! great spotting @romainl - when setting up the regex, I thought the `.\1` backreference  was inserted at the *end* of each line in the ctags file - and hence that was what ctag completion was based on, I removed the dot and bam its working! hah Ive spent hours messing around with this!!

Comment: Thanks for the link to your ctags too. Im giving your config for javascript a try and its  working nicely for completion and jumping to definition . Im also using tern for javascript completion - so far the two seem to go together quite well !

Comment: Cool, glad it helps.